# Why do compilers allow a data member have the same name as the class?

Tags: c++, class, c++17, language-lawyer, declaration

Three major compilers (gcc, clang, MSVC) happily compile the following example ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAOykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAArKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BASlpGQKh4VEssfFJdpgOmUIETMQE2T5%2BgVU1AnUNBMWRMXGJtvWNzbltwz1hfWUDCQCUtqhexMjsHAoExF4OANQAKpgbJhoAgib%2BVqc71zthBDfXB0cAzJdnpwD0Hw9e6UY3ymIqFiOxMzwAIrdBGC3l8HncHjtAcDMDDjmd/OC0ad0QiWEwwhA5ujzm8Hk97jdVNiTg9VAA6CmgiE7SQ087gjgLWicBK8PwcLSkVCcNzWaw7BRLFaYUFmZ48UgETRchYAaxAZkk9IAnHr9QaDQA2fScST8lXCzi8BQgDRKlULOCwJBoFjJOhxciUN0e%2BjxZAGIxcI0ae1YABueFWADU8JgAO4AeWSjE4ipotAIcVtEGiluiYQaAE907xC8xiMWk9FtNVldxeG62IIkwxaKXBbwsPijOIu6R8MR63gI4dLZhVNUvNmy%2BRBJgeQPaHhosQSx4sJbNngWGWFlQDMAFHHEym042ZIIRGJ2FIr/IlGpLbouPpDMZxZZ9KvbZAFqgySOAItocDai4js4ECuKMfhviEUylOUeipOkwFZJ4LQoQU6G9EhAxvu06FdCMmG5IREEdAwJGTCU/TxIREywXoGzdHh9ESAsUrLKsnGmhwfKkAKQoihwOyqAAHEaAC0RqSDsgYfjsIb0hoqk7BAuCECQcoKnMvANloczqpq2qGuZ%2Bomku5pCZaok2naDpdk6MCICgqDup6ZAUBAvpeSAx7MMkCgIKgBCDpgUaxvGyapgKGZ0NmxC5vmA4ViWc7pVWNZ1g4c7NowBBth2lo9h%2B/ZCkOI5jqBQqTtOs6Xnci6Wiua4bhgaxCjue6NgeR4njF57xbw/DXqI4j3mNj4qOoA66GY75GCgX42G1f5EsKQGZKB4H2OhLgMO4ZFwUER3sTMDH5GhmTMW%2BqGFAwF3IRR%2B21ExJ0sZRxETM9BFDN0d0A40f0MVx0q8Vw3K8haA6ieJUmyfJwDIMgGmbF4DBqnMGlaUQxC6VDBmOiZWq6hZ5lWWasMidatiOYZXKkM6bl%2Bf63q%2BR5foDBGyDJMkAD6EZcDqAsGNmGwC5JJqRtGmCnrFF4JVmOaUKlQpZZ2iqazl9b5R5LZFe2naVZgvbABV3Z4MONQ1ROU7IDOayKs1S5Cm165VpuXUGcQu77nwA0K8Nc7TTek3SNNiizS%2BIDPEtn6WNYP7RBtAHbSBdNEZkh3HTkp0IXRl3YTdAhAw9uGIRxr2QdRH3519b2dL9VfF4xgOfe3IOty94M8Xe0MCTTvDw9LOwsAovM7MLOr0uLhz3Jp%2BD44T%2BlOUZpNJNZw9WmB9P2ozxn8WYO/2evqqkGOyU55IQA)):

```
struct Test
{
    // Member type `Test::Test` is supposedly introduced at this point
    // as an alias to `struct Test`, per
    // https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class#2

    // Shouldn't the following declaration be rejected since it redefines
    // the name `Test` in the same scope?
    // https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup#3
    int     Test;

    // Doing the same explicitly would be a compilation error, as expected:
    // using   Probe = int;
    // int     Probe;
};

int main()
{
    Test    x;
    x.Test = 4;
}
```

**Is the above example well-formed?** and why. Why doesn't [injected-class-name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name) render the declaration of member `int Test;` invalid?

<strike>Lookup rule [wrong reference to a newer standard] that might have made the example ill-formed with no diagnostic seem irrelevant, as no lookup happens here until the class is complete. What other clauses are relevant to this example?</strike>

Comment: You are referencing the C++23 draft, but you tagged C++17. I would suggest making this consistent, since the rules for declarations and lookup have had a large overhaul for C++23.

Comment: @user17732522, you're right; I've updated the links and removed the part which I was unable to back up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the C++17 Standard (12.2 Class members)

> 18 If T is the name of a class, then each of the following shall have
> a name different from T:
>
> (18.1) — every static data member of class T;
>
> (18.2) — every member function of class T [ Note: This restriction
> does not apply to constructors, which do not have names (15.1) — end
> note ] ;
>
> (18.3) — every member of class T that is itself a type;
>
> (18.4) — every member template of class T;
>
> (18.5) — every enumerator of every member of class T that is an
> unscoped enumerated type; and
>
> (18.6) — every member of every anonymous union that is a member of
> class T.

and

> 19 In addition, if class T has a user-declared constructor (15.1),
> every non-static data member of class T shall have a name different
> from T.

So as your class does not have a user-declared constructor then its non-static data member `Test` may have the same name as the class name.

You may even write

```
Test Test;
Test.Test = 4;
```

(It seems it is allowed for compatibility with C where structure tag names and names of data members belong to different name spaces.)

On the other hand, if you will declare a constructor as for example

```
struct Test
{
    Test() = default;
    int     Test;
};
```

then the compiler will issue an error.

In general C++ does not allow for example to declare a variable and a function with the same name in the same scope.

Comment: Here's a link to that quote in the final draft: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mem#18 I wonder why it doesn't also say "has a user-declared constructor *or destructor*" https://godbolt.org/z/j71rf4aEj

Comment: What about the lookup `x.Test`?

Comment: @user17732522 _A qualified lookup Test::Test will always be considered to name the constructor (and it seems to me in the C++23 draft an unqualified member access x.Test also does)_ http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.general#4.sentence-2?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I reread it and withdraw my previous comments. If I understand correctly now, the qualified lookup should remove the injected-class-name from the results of the (single) search before [class.qual] is applied. So it should always name the non-static data member `Test`. I assumed the order was reversed. GCC seems to get this wrong then (https://godbolt.org/z/YqEdjfzEc).

Comment: @user17732522 Hm. If the lookup for the first `Test` in `x.Test::Test` gives the NSDM, then `::Test` in NSDM shall not work? And GCC is right to not accept the program.

Comment: @user17732522 or by «wrong» you meant the error message wording?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer That anyway, but the name lookup rules still often confuse me.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer, scope operator has higher precedence than member access operator. So, `x.Test::Test` should be grouped as `x.(Test::Test)`, if you pardon my pseudocode syntax.

Comment: Vlad, thank you for the explanation! I do understand the intent to keep compatibility with C structures, but I'm puzzled why it's conditional on explicitly declared constructor. For example, adding a virtual abstract base class to `Test` pushes it really far from C POD. But still, same member name seems allowed...

Comment: @IgorG _scope operator has higher precedence than member access operator. So, `x.Test::Test` should be grouped as `x.(Test::Test)`_ Not sure what are you trying to say. That the first `Test` undergoes unqualified lookup?

Comment: @IgorG As it follows from the C++ Standard it is important that the class where a data member with the same name  is declared does not have a user declared constructor.